# django-socialregistration facebook registration fail in chromium

Tags: javascript, django, oauth

Implementing and using django-socialregistration worked out pretty easy, but when trying my application in Chromium I get an error while registering/logging in via facebook. Firefox and Opera works as a charm. The problem occurs after clicking the button provided by:

`{% load facebook_tags %} 
 {% facebook_button %} 
 {% facebook_js %}`

and I'm redirected to the facebook_login-view in socialregistration.views.
It seems that request.facebook.uid is None, so I'm redirected to an error-view here:

```
def facebook_login(request, template='socialregistration/facebook.html',
extra_context=dict(), account_inactive_template='socialregistration/account_inactive.html'):
"""
View to handle the Facebook login
"""
if request.facebook.uid is None:
    logging.debug("No facebook uid")
    extra_context.update(dict(error=FB_ERROR))
    return render_to_response(template, extra_context,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I noticed that the javascript following the use of the facebook-tags in the template gives an warning in the console saying

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?.......frame with URL http://localhost:8000/user/register/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Could this warning be a reason for the register/login not to work in Chromium but in other browsers?